# Using an equality check between columns in a SELECT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, equality

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and I would like to run this seemingly simple query:

```
SELECT 
    FirstEvent.id AS firstEventID, 
    SecondEvent.id AS secondEventID, 
    DATEDIFF(second, FirstEvent.WndFGEnd, SecondEvent.WndFGStart) AS gap, 
    FirstEvent.TitleID = SecondEvent.TitleID AS titlesSameCheck
FROM VibeFGEvents AS FirstEvent
RIGHT OUTER JOIN VibeFGEvents AS SecondEvent
ON 
    FirstEvent.intervalMode = SecondEvent.intervalMode 
    AND FirstEvent.id = SecondEvent.id - 1 
    AND FirstEvent.logID = SecondEvent.logID
```

However `FirstEvent.TitleID = SecondEvent.TitleID AS titlesSameCheck` in the `SELECT` clause is incorrect syntax. But [the SELECT Clause (Transact-SQL) documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176104.aspx) includes this syntax:

```
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]
[ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] [ WITH TIES ] ] 
<select_list> 
<select_list> ::= 
    { 
        * 
        | { table_name | view_name | table_alias }.* 
        | {
            [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ]
                { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID } 
            | udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name } 
            | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ]
            | expression
            [ [ AS ] column_alias ] 
            }
        | column_alias = expression 
    } [ ,...n ]
```

I think that means an expression is valid in the select clause and indeed the examples given include things like `1 + 2`. Looking at [the documentation for expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190286.aspx):

```
{ constant | scalar_function | [ table_name. ] column | variable 
    | ( expression ) | ( scalar_subquery ) 
    | { unary_operator } expression 
    | expression { binary_operator } expression 
    | ranking_windowed_function | aggregate_windowed_function
}
```

boolean equality checks are valid expressions and indeed the example expression given in [the = (Equals) (Transact-SQL) documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118.aspx) includes one:

```
SELECT DepartmentID, Name
FROM HumanResources.Department
WHERE GroupName = 'Manufacturing'
```

albeit in the `WHERE` clause not the `SELECT` clause. It looks like I cannot use `=` the equality operator to compare expressions in my `SELECT` clause as they are being wrongly interpreted as assignment.

How do I include a Boolean equality column comparison equivalent to `FirstEvent.TitleID = SecondEvent.TitleID AS titlesSameCheck` in my `SELECT` clause?

Comment: Take a closer look at `<select_list>` definition: `column_alias = expression` is an alternative form of column aliasing.

Comment: I saw that, but I would expect the compiler to be able to distinguish aliasing from comparison. For me personally keeping them separate (aliasing using `AS`, assignment using `=`, and comparison using `==`) but I guess there are historic reasons why tSQL is not clear cut like that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Like this:

```
case when FirstEvent.TitleID = SecondEvent.TitleID then 1 else 0 end as titlesSameCheck
```

Answer (score 20):

You cannot use the Boolean type directly except in conditional statements (case, where, having, etc.)

Best way to solve your problem is to do something like

```
select case when x = y then 'true' else 'false' end
```

The `bit` type is probably the closest to boolean.

```
select CAST(case when x = y then 1 else 0 end as bit)
```

Of course, use whichever two values best represent what you are after.

Comment: I didn't down-vote but I would recommend against using string 'true'/'false'. Sql has bit(boolean) and it should be used.

Answer (score 2):

As the two existing answers state, boolean values can't be returned as a column value. This is documented in the [Comparison Operators section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188074.aspx):

> Unlike other SQL Server data types, a Boolean data type cannot be
>   specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot
>   be returned in a result set.

Given that restriction, using `CASE` to transform the value to something that can be displayed is your best alternative.

Comment: +1 for pointing to where in the documentation I may actually have deduced this from; thanks Allan